# How to get lowest latency between two AWS regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-direct-connect, aws-global-accelerator

My EC2 instance is located in AWS-East-1 (US). It makes rest calls to a server (crypto exchange) hosted in AWS Tokyo. Currently, over the internet, it takes 175ms for data packet round trip.

How can I achieve lowest latency in this connection? I have read about AWS Global Accelerator, Direct Link/Connect etc. but I am not sure what's the right solution here.

Kindly explain the best architecture for network packet routing and whether I can use an existing AWS service for this.

Comment: What are you expecting for latency? It's 75ms to make that roundtrip at the speed of light, and packets can't go that fast. If you need low latency, move your EC2 server to Tokyo.

Comment: Actually, I need to use the information generated on Binance (AWS Tokyo) to trade at Coinbase (AWS US). Also, every millisecond counts here as this is for an HFT program. I know that private telecom operators can offer 106ms for an optimized route between these locations. However, they are obviously quite expensive. Hence, trying to understand what best can be achieved with standard AWS offerings.

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Comment: Hello did you find the solution. I’m also facing same issue, could you share the solution if you have found

Comment: @KrisHJodu I was told by AWS team that they already use their own AWS backend to route traffic between two datacenters. So that's pretty optimized. I was able to cut down from 175ms to 144ms by configuring network settings on AWS instances. Beyond this, you need to speak to private telecom operators like Avelacom to cut this down to 134ms. They have their own fiber cables which are more optimized for speed. Some routes even have microwaves which is very expensive but then beats fiber hands down. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Dan what kind of changes you made by configurations? Could you please share some details? I also have similar issue.